# product count in layred navigation filter include only in stock products magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

Is there a way to show only in stock product count in shop by layered navigation filters? i need to show out of stock products in frontend, But not need to include its count in filters such as shop by price, shop by category etc.
Is there any possible way? i have checked the code. But struggling to achieve. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think this question is answer already. kindly check this [link][1] 


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/magento-hiding-and-not-counting-out-of-stock-in-layered-navigation/13546#13546

Comment: no.. it doesnt provide proper answer Qaisar..

Comment: Could anybody assist me in doing this. Thanks..

Comment: Please help me in this. still struggling to achieve..

Comment: what did you do so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute**  in this function count the product for filter

```
protected function _getItemsData()
{
    $attribute = $this->getAttributeModel();
    $this->_requestVar = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

    $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey() . '_' . $this->_requestVar;
    $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

    if ($data === null) {
        $options = $attribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();
        $optionsCount = $this->_getResource()->getCount($this);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if (is_array($option['value'])) {
                continue;
            }
            if (Mage::helper('core/string')->strlen($option['value'])) {
                // Check filter type
                if ($this->_getIsFilterableAttribute($attribute) == self::OPTIONS_ONLY_WITH_RESULTS) {
                    if (!empty($optionsCount[$option['value']])) {
                        $data[] = array(
                            'label' => $option['label'],
                            'value' => $option['value'],
                            'count' => $optionsCount[$option['value']],
                        );
                    }
                } else {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'label' => $option['label'],
                        'value' => $option['value'],
                        'count' => isset($optionsCount[$option['value']]) ? $optionsCount[$option['value']] : 0,
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        $tags = array(
            Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::CACHE_TAG . ':' . $attribute->getId()
        );

        $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags($tags);
        $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
    }

    return $data;
}

protected function _getCount($var)
{
    // Clone the select
    $select = clone $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();

    $pid1 = $select->getAllIds();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->joinField('rating_summary',
            'review_entity_summary',
            'rating_summary',
            'entity_pk_value=entity_id',
            array('entity_type' => 1, 'store_id' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()),
            'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $pid1))
        ->load();

    return count($products);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. YES. I have seen it. But do you know how come we cna add filter here so out of stock product not included in count?

Comment: when i create the module i used this function for count the product.get the idea from it because you can add your collection here..

Comment: please ans this- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100990/getting-wrong-final-price-for-configurable-products

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the model

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php
```

and override the method getCount()