# Getting Wrong Maximum Price For Configurable Products

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I am trying to get final price for price slider but it is showing me wrong price.
See below images, Price should be 4000/- for right slider but it is showing me 2000.

**Input Price--**
[image]

**Output Price--**
[image]

Any Help Appreciated.

Code Where I get Maximum Price-

```
public function getCurrMaxPrice(){
    if($this->_currMaxPrice > 0)
    {
        $max = $this->_currMaxPrice;
    } else
    {
     $max = $this->_maxPrice;
    }

 $max;
    return $max;
}
```

Comment: it will calculate after the option is selected it is showing price starting from. not the final price check on cart page what final price of this product..

Comment: No I tried code to get final price and it is still showing wrong price.

Comment: this is the base price of this product?

Comment: See I have just changed both images

Comment: yes, 2000 is the base price of the product

Comment: you have to get maxprice not final price from collection to set for slide

Comment: how to get max-price

Comment: can you post where you getting the price for slider?

Comment: Just Added above.

Comment: can you confirm me are you adding the price slider in layered navigation?

Comment: Yes I have added this.

Comment: did you override the price module or working in phtml file?

Comment: Yes I did I override

Answer (score 1):

simple add this function in your `price model`

```
public function getPrices()
    {  
          $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();

         $data[]=array('from' =>$collection->getMinPrice(),
            'to' =>$collection->getMaxPrice());
         return $data;
    }
```

in your `price block`

get them like that

```
public function getPrices()
{                          
     return Mage::getModel($this->_filterModelName)->getPrices();
}
```

this will give maximum and minimum price for recent collection

this is model core class

`Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php`

core block price

`Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Price.php`

**Don't change in core files** if you want to change them copy in `app/code/local`

Comment: could you give me path?

Answer (score 0):

It will be 2000 because the item listed has the maximum amount of 2000.
Include all 3 products to the same category. Land on the category page. You will see 4000 as max price in slider. Price slider gets maximum priced item. So in your case it is 2000

Comment: Ok, I have just changed 2nd product price to 3000/- and now slider showing me 0 - 3000. But not 4000 why?

Comment: First of all change the visibility of all products to Catalog and Search

Comment: If the product with amount 4000 is listed there on the page,then  it will show you the max price to 4000. Otherwise it will not.

Comment: I have just changed the images 2000/- is the base price of the product and 4000 is the max price the why I am not getting this 4000/- why only 3000/-?

Comment: By setting visibility to Catalog and Search still it is not showing correct price.