# Only display products with stock when filter is selected

Tags: magento2, filter

guys so recently I noticed that when I select a filter, for example, the size `M` some of the products even though they have the size `M` some of them are out of stock and I was wondering if it's possible to overwrite the search function or add new functionality so it doesn't display products that don't have stock in size `M` for example.

To better explain my problem:

- User selects filter of size `M`;
- Products with size `M` in stock and out of stock are displayed

What I would like to know is if it's possible to only display products where the filter in the example `M` is in stock.

I read some posts but all of them are some hacky unstable modifications and I would like to avoid that as much as possible since this is intended to go into production.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link is having the answer of your question https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154654/95067
Please try it sir.

From admin panel

It can manage from admin panel follow the following steps

login admin

go to "system"--> "Configuration"

in that goto left side navigation bar "Catalog"--->"Inventory"

then goto right side tabs there is 2 tabs in that click on "Stock Options"

in that tab change "yes" for "Display Out of Stock Products" Option

Comment: That answer is a hack to the current way its indexing which I would like to avoid